# LESS work-flow with Atom

Tags: less

I am trying to get Atom to work with LESS and I can't find the correct way.

This is my folder structure:

/css/main.less

/css/partials/base.less

/css/partials/forms.less

...

I want to build main.less every time I save a partial but not build the partial itself. How can I do that? I think I tried all packages related to LESS and none of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found why I wasn't able to make it work.

I am using the package [atom-less](https://atom.io/packages/atom-less) which I tried before. The only thing I did different is restarting Atom after package installation.

Following the instructions of the package is enough to make it work. In my case:

comment on the first line of main.less:

// "out": "main.css", "sourcemap": false, "compress": true, "autoprefixer": false

comment on the first line of one partial:

// "main": "../main.less"